# netcat not found in Amazon AMI (Centos)

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, netcat

I followed [this guide](http://blog.taggesell.de/index.php?/archives/85-Amazon-EC2-How-to-migrate-an-EBS-backed-image-from-US-to-EU-or-wherever.html) to migrate my amazon image from one zone to another. Everything goes fine, but when i run this command:

```
netcat -p 9999 -l >/dev/sdf
```

It shows that the command is not found. Then i tried to use nc instead:

```
nc -p 9999 -l >/dev/sdf
```

It seems that nc cannot be run with the combination of -p and -l option. What is the exactly same command i should run on my system in equivalent to "netcat -p 9999 -l >/dev/sdf" ?

i am using "Basic 32-bit Amazon Linux AMI 2011.02.1 Beta" as my primary image. It seems that it's centos based. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Archive of the linked post found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20130410051019/http://blog.taggesell.de/index.php?/archives/85-Amazon-EC2-How-to-migrate-an-EBS-backed-image-from-US-to-EU-or-wherever.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some `nc` versions has `-p` option with different meaning:

```
-p source_port
             Specifies the source port nc should use, subject to privilege restrictions and availability.  It is
             an error to use this option in conjunction with the -l option.
```

while another:

```
-p port      local port number (port numbers can be individual or ranges: lo-hi [inclusive])
```

In your case, just use `nc -l 9999 > /dev/sdf` is enough.