# something like telnet, but "listen on", not "connect to"

Tags: telnet, listener

With the telnet program one can connect to any TCP port on any host, but is there a way to listen on some port on current host?

i.e.

1) on host a:
telnet listen 12345

2) on host b:
telnet host_a 12345

I don't want any service behind the listening side, just connection and whatever typed to be transferred as is both ways.

I know I can already do the 2), but is there any way to achieve the 1)? I'm interested in both Windows and Linux solution.

Comment: wireshark (tcpdump)?

Comment: @Anders: Nope, that doesn't open the port, and the peer will get its connection refused instead of finishing the 3-way handshake.

Answer (score 50):

The usual tool for this is something called `netcat`. It's available in most Linux distros, and may even be installed by default in some (the command is `nc`). There are even ports for Windows, but nearly every antivirus package on the planet considers it deeply suspicious due it's use in malware which makes it hard to download and use.

Comment: Note that the `nc` tool which is installed in __cygwin__ is a different implementation than the `ncat` tool which is installed with __nmpap__. For example the command `nc -v -l xxx xx ` on __cygwin__ doesn't print the ip of the remote host or when a connection is establish by a remote client. On the contrary if you have nmap installed the command `ncat -v -l xxx xx` gives you this important details. This is why I prefer to use `ncat` instead of `nc`. *Another advantage of `ncat` is that probably it is not black listed by the AV software*.

Answer (score 21):

> 1) on host a: telnet listen 12345

```
$ ls | nc -l -p 12345
```

Depends on the distro and netcat version, you may not need [`-p`](https://serverfault.com/questions/303719/netcat-not-found-in-amazon-ami-centos) option.

> 2) on host b: telnet host_a 12345

```
$ telnet host_a 12345
1159.rar
12030.mp4
123.mp4
124.mp4
129
129.bak
...
```

Comment: Why do you pipe the file directory list command "ls" to nc?

Answer (score 13):

You are looking for a program called [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/). It is the swiss army knife of network utilities. You can tell it to listen on any arbitrary port as well as many other things.

Answer (score 4):

Netcat, is what you're looking for.

http://netcat.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

Download Netcat. Swiss army knife of network utilities. http://netcat.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Even better than `netcat` is [`socat`](http://freecode.com/projects/socat).

It provides a lot more control over socket options, and also many more choices for where to send received data.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Maniac can listen on any TCP and UDP port in Windows world