# Is there a "server" version of telnet?

Tags: socket, telnet

If I want to quickly connect to a socket as a client and type something I can use telnet.

Is there a version of telnet or a similar program that provides the server-side of this?

In other words, is there some sort of "telnetserver" program I can connect to with telnet and then have a text chat with myself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [something like telnet, but "listen on", not "connect to"](https://serverfault.com/questions/326044/something-like-telnet-but-listen-on-not-connect-to)

Comment: Thanks for that.   I searched but didn't find it.  No need for downvotes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telnet provides a lot more than would be required for your simple use case: according to Telnet Protocol Specification ([RFC 854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854)):

> The TELNET Protocol is built upon three main ideas:  first, the
> concept of a "Network Virtual Terminal"; second, the principle of
> negotiated options; and third, a symmetric view of terminals and
> processes.

You don't need any of these, as you simply want to send and receive messages. **Netcat** can handle these simple TCP connections on both ends. Here, the `-vvv` is just for verbosity, to better understand what's happening.

- Server

  ```
   $ nc -l 12765 -vvv
   Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 2, port 12765)
   Connection from client.example.net 58724 received!
  ```
- Client

  ```
   $ nc example.com 12765 -vvv
   example.com [192.0.2.1] 12765 (?) open
  ```

Now, whatever is typed into either one of these appears in the other, after hitting enter.

Comment: Thank you my friend.